# Programmatically create an iPhone UIView inside an UIView and draw inside it

Tags: iphone, uiview, core-graphics

I'm building a custom UIView for some custom drawing. So I subclassed UIView - MyUICustomView --.

**Into this UIView**'s `drawRect` method, I'd like to programmatically include another view - `MyMovingView` - inside which I want to draw some CG graphics, then move that new drawn subview around inside my main view (the one that `MyUICustomView` own).

Comment: Can you specify what you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Step 1) Create two views, MyUICustomView and MyMovingView
Step 2) Add MyMovingView to MyUICustomView
Step 3) In MyMovingView add custom drawing routines (CGGraphics) to drawRect
Step 4) In MyUICustomView add UIGestureRecognizer routines to move MyMovingView around
```

Pretty Simple. (A generic answer for a generic question). If you'd like to be more specific we can provide some more detail.